# I have an array of objects with a count and page params. How can I find the last data of array and if its less than count dont load the next page

Tags: reactjs, pagination

Im trying to to make my data paginated but when the data reaches the end it still adds one more page which returns a blank screen.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js">
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0)

  const vendors = useGetVendorsQuery({
    isSameDayRelease: sameDaySearch,
    region: selectedTab,
    name: vendorNameSearch,
    address: locationSearch,
    page: pageNumber,
    count: 50
  })

const handleScroll = (e: any) => {
      // Adds page if next page exists
    if(vendors?.data?.length <= 49){
      setPageNumber(0)
    } else if (bottom) { 
      setPageNumber((prevPageNumber) => prevPageNumber + 1)
        console.log(vendors.data)
     } 
  }
  }</script>
```

The way I have it above technically works but if it has exactly 50 in the array it'll load the next page blank

Comment: Are you sure vendors?.data?.length is returning 50 items?
If so your first if condition is false, and else if adds a new page.
If you dont want a new page, do vendors?.data?.length <= 50

Comment: @ArbinShrestha If I say <= 50 nothing will load on the page as the count is 50 max